# Open New Task Modal After Saving a Record

Tags: lightning, tasks

I want to open the new task modal window after a record is saved that has a value in a certain field.  For example, if I have a picklist view and the user choose "Value A" from the picklist, saves the record, I want to then open up the stanard new task window somehow.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried or researched?

Comment: Which is the object the will have this pick-list?

Answer (score 0):

High level suggestion to get you moving in the right direction: You'll have to use LDS within an Aura/Lightning Web Component on the record page in question. When a User updates the record, your LDS implementation should evaluate the specific picklist field's value for "Value A". If true, set some attribute/variable to TRUE. This attribute/variable should be used in an `<aura:if>` or `<template if:true>` which encapsulates a Task record edit form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably can use **Process Builder** to get something something similar, but not initial modal. 
If you want to recreate the standard new **Task** on a field change when a field changes, you are going to face a complex scenario.

My approach for this will be to create a **Process Builder** that will create a **Task** record with whatever values you initially need. You can also alert the user of this operation and he/she can then go to the new **Task** and add any extra information if it is really necessary.

So you can go to **SetUp** --> **Process Automation** --> **Process Builder**
Click on **New**
Give a **Process Name**
**The process starts when** = **Record Changes**
**Save**

Select your object, the one with the picklist that you want to execute the new Task. Using the **Account** object for this test.

[image]

Then the **Criteria**, on my test is the '**FieldSet**'. Click that box and set up the field that you want and the value that should fire the Task.

Now click on **Add Action**:
[image]

From the **Action Type*** select **Create a Record**
Add the **Action Name**
Select **Record Type** = **Task**

Configure all the fields you need, **Save** ... 
Click on **Activate** on the Top right conner... Done

This is a much easier way and better approach that can make that business requirement lest painful. When a task is create you can have all kind of operations to alert the owner of any particular need, if any.

Don't know if this help.. but is worth a try ...